# Call method any time a view is tapped Android - Java

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, gesture

Is there a way to have a method called any time a touch occurs in an activity and get its id?

I have a custom view that I add to the relative layout, and then anytime a tap is register outside that custom view I want to hide the custom view. What is the best way to go about this.

I tried adding a `oncliecllistner` to the Relative layout but that didn't work, because it only registered taps on the Relative layout, so when I tap on the textview that are children of the relative layout it was not called. And since the custom view and the relative layout overlap sometime when I tapped on the custom view it would register as a tap on the relative layout

Thanks

Comment: "I tried adding a oncliecllistner to the Relative layout but that didnt work." - please post your code and explain what exactly didn't work.

Comment: Add onClickListener to your RelativeLayout to hide your custom view. This will make clicking on your custom view also to hide it, so add onClickListener to your custom view just to intercept click event.

Comment: @Gudin if I add on listener to my custom view, how do I know when there is a tap outside to custom view to hide it?

Comment: add another listener to your top view (e.g. Relative Layout that represent whole screen).

Comment: @Gudin that what I originally did, was add an on click listener to the relative layout

Comment: "so when I tap on the textview that are children of the relative layout it was not called." I guess then you should set focusable false to those views

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add a transparent empty `View` (let's give it the id `overlayView`) that overlays everything in the layout, *except* for the View that you want to be hidable (let's give that the id `bashful`):

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!--
         All your existing non-bashful Views must be here, *before* overlayView.
         That gives them a lower Z-order than overlayView.
     -->

    <View
        android:id="@+id/overlayView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

    <!-- The bashful View must come last, so that it has the highest Z-order. -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/bashful"
        ...
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in the `View.OnTouchListener` (NOT `View.OnClickListener`) for `overlayView`, you can do this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    mBashfulView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

This code assumes that you have a `mBashfulView` variable that references the `bashful` View.

The listener will only be invoked if the user touches anywhere outside the `bashful` View.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using `dispatchTouchEvent()`. This is a function that your activity can override (has the signature `public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`) and it will intercept ALL touch events to the screen. Inside this function you will be able to decide what to do with the touch event. If you determine that you don't want to do anything special, and should allow the user's touch to proceed as normal, just call `super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)`!

Some documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)